# How to use an SSD (device: /dev/nvme0n1) to install all the libraries instead of /home?

Tags: boot, mount, ssd, fstab

I am working with an NVIDIA Xavier NX and the kit does not have any memory except for 8GB RAM. So I used a 16GB SD card to flash the kit (this SD is used for the booting purposes) and then put on a Samsung 500GB SSD on the back. Now I can see that the system sees the SSD because `Disks` program shows me that a 500GB Samsung SSD is detected.

My `/home` folder shows that it only has ~350 MB memory left so I don't want to install anything on here but directly on SSD so that I always have enough space. Is there a way to do this? Maybe some kind of symlink or changing `/home` to the SSD?

I tried mounting `/home` onto `/dev/nvme0n1` before once and then editing the `/etc/fstab` file to add the UUID of the SSD but /home still showed the same amount of space as before and moreover, when I rebooted the kit, it stopped booting up. I had to reflash the kit to be able to get it working again.

Please help regarding how I can achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Your /home only has your user settings & data. All the system is in / and 16GB is tight for / anyway. I typically use 30GB for / partition, but have all data in separate data partitions. And aggressively house clean, logs & cruft that normally builds and current using 9GB of my 30GB with a fair number of applications. You may be able to move some other system partitions to SSD. But will system boot from SSD directly? Or full install on SSD. Or just /boot on flash drive and rest of system on SSD? The more of system on SSD, the faster it will be as SSD lot faster than flash card.

Comment: The system boots from the 16 GB SD card and then it should run from the SSD directly so that the SSD's memory can be used for the system files. Unfortunately, Xavier NX does not allow a full boot from the SSD directly so the SD card is needed for the initial boot process. 
I found a solution from an article and posted an answer following the instructions from there. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found this [article](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2020/05/29/jetson-xavier-nx-run-from-ssd/) on JetsonHacks which solves the problem. In short:

1. Install the SSD on the Xavier NX kit.
2. Use the `Disks` program from Dash to see if the SSD is detected.
3. Create a partition on the SSD.
4. Clone this [repo](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/rootOnNVMe): `git clone https://github.com/jetsonhacks/rootOnNVMe`.
5. Go into the `rootOnNVMe` folder: `cd rootOnNVMe`.
6. This script copies the rootfs from the SD card to the SSD: `./copy-rootfs-ssd.sh`.
7. Finally, this script points the root to the SSD so that the system runs from the SSD directly after booting up: `./setup-service.sh`.

Reboot the kit and it should be running from SSD directly.